# Context Returns Results View Empty, When records exist in table

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, frameworks, entity

I'm having an issue with one table in my context. It contains records in the database, but when I call context.MyTable.ToList(), I get zero records. I'm using the same context for many other tables and they all return records just fine.

Comment: Is the data in the database correct? Did you check the changetracker?https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/changetracker-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: The database is the same as I'm using for 20 other tables that all return records as expected. I added the DisplayStates test code to two of my get statements and both came back with zero entries, both for the get that returns zero records and a get that returns records as expected.